# How to Concatenate Two LPCSTRs

Tags: c++, concatenation, lpcstr

I have two LPCSTRs I need to concatenate like so:

```
if (!rename(directory + originalFileName, directory + fileName)){
    std::cout<<originalFileName<<std::endl<<fileName<<std::endl<<std::endl;
}
```

The only problem however is that I can't use the `+` operator here. How can I safely concatenate two LPCSTRs like this?

EDIT: Note that an LPCSTR is defined as a `const * char` while an LPCTSTR is defined as `const TCHAR*`. The two are different when UNICODE and/or _UNICODE are defined. In this case, they are.

Comment: LPCTSTR is not the same as an LPCSTR

Comment: Sorry my mistake.  I didn't notice the extra T.

Comment: `std::string(directory).append(originalFileName).c_str()` - used properly will do what you want.

Comment: "The two are different." - the two are only different when UNICODE and/or _UNICODE are defined, which you made no mention of in your question.

Comment: Edited. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to WhozCraig, I got the answer:

```
LPCSTR str1 = "foo",
       str2 = "bar";

std::string(str1).append(str2).c_str();
std::cout<<str1;
```

Returns

```
foobar
```

Comment: Nice job --- I suspect you won't be "a terrible programmer" for very long!

Comment: This answer is wrong as it returns a dangling pointer. When working with raw pointers you must always think about the lifetime of the object the pointer is pointing to.

Answer (score 5):

Since `LPCSTR` is a `CONST CHAR*` i used this,

```
(string(dir) + string(originalFileName)).c_str()
```

Comment: Note that this can only be used so long as you do not use the result past the end of the *full-expression* containing it

Answer (score 2):

Since these strings are const you will need a new buffer to hold the results. That means finding the length of the strings with 'strlen', allocating a buffer with 'new', and copying the strings with 'strcpy' and 'strcat'

That's a hint for how to learn it, instead of me writing the code for you.

Also, there are other options such as using std::string or CString depending on your toolset.

Comment: Not to be lazy or anything, but wouldn't it be more constructive to provide code for anyone who comes across this question in future?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `std::string` class to do the heavy lifting because it contains overloaded `operator+`. However you must ensure that the `std::string` object is not destroyed before you attempt to read its contents.

One way (in C++03) would be:

```
std::string dest = std::string(directory) + originalFileName;
std::string src = std::string(directory) + fileName;

if (!rename(dest.c_str(), src.c_str())
    // whatever...
```

Consider storing `directory` as a `std::string` in the first place.